# ionicV3 back button navigation problem showing nav.getActive is not a function

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, navbar

I am trying to overwrite the navigation back button to my needs in android using ionic 3 but whenever i run my app it shows an error when i press back navigation button saying "`nav.getActive` is not a function" due to this back button doesn't work.

### **Updated Code is as followed**

```
export class MyApp {

  rootPage:any = LoginPage;
  public counter=0;
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,public globalProvider: GlobalProvider,
    public googlePlus: GooglePlus, public zone: NgZone, private readonly firebase: Firebase, private alertCtrl: AlertController, 
    public toastCtrl: ToastController, public  app: App) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
       splashScreen.hide();
       platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {


       const activeView = this.nav.getActive().name // This will give you the activeview name               

         if(activeView === 'HomePage') {

             if (this.nav.canGoBack()){ //Can we go back?
                 this.nav.pop();
             } else {
                 const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                     title: 'App termination',
                     message: 'Do you want to close the app?',
                     buttons: [{
                         text: 'Cancel',
                         role: 'cancel',
                         handler: () => {
                             console.log('Application exit prevented!');
                         }
                     },{
                         text: 'Close App',
                         handler: () => {
                             platform.exitApp(); // Close this application
                         }
                     }]
                 });
                 alert.present();
             }
         }
         this.nav.push(TabsPage);
     }, 1);

      this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe(notification => {
          console.log('notification info: ', notification);

          /*!notification.tap
              ? console.log('The user was using the app when the notification arrived...')
              : console.log('The app was closed when the notification arrived...');

          let notificationAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: notification.title,
              message: notification.body,
              buttons: ['Ok']
          });
          notificationAlert.present();*/
      },
      error => {
          console.error('Error getting the notification', error);
      });             
 });

       /*platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
        if (this.counter == 0) {
          this.counter++;
          this.presentToast();
          setTimeout(() => { this.counter = 0 }, 3000)
        } else {
          // console.log("exitapp");
          platform.exitApp();
        }
      }, 0) });*/
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
    @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
    constructor(platform: Platform,
         statusBar: StatusBar,
         splashScreen: SplashScreen,
         public globalProvider: GlobalProvider, 
         public toastCtrl: ToastController,
         public googlePlus: GooglePlus,
         public zone: NgZone,
         public  app: App, 
         public alertCtrl: AlertController
    ) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {

      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
       statusBar.styleDefault();
       splashScreen.hide();
       platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {

       **const activeView = this.nav.getActive().name** // This will give you the activeview name               

        if(active.instance instanceof HomePage) {

            if (nav.canGoBack()){ //Can we go back?
                nav.pop();
            } else {
                const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                    title: 'App termination',
                    message: 'Do you want to close the app?',
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        role: 'cancel',
                        handler: () => {
                            console.log('Application exit prevented!');
                        }
                    },{
                        text: 'Close App',
                        handler: () => {
                            platform.exitApp(); // Close this application
                        }
                    }]
                });
                alert.present();
            }
        }
        nav.push(HomePage);
    }, 100);
});
}
```

Comment: sry for late reply, m using ur code it is working partially as its doing the job getting back to home page but the if condition is not triggering to exit the app it just refresh the current page and doesn't exit. also i use
if(activeView === 'HomePage') as cant use instance of as it declared const. 
can u help in assisting the code so that i can make it work

Comment: Have you set the HomePage as Root page? What error you are getting?

Comment: my home page is actually TabsPage and root page is loginPage but whenever i am running the app it logs in i navigate to any other page when i press back button i am taken to TabsPage(homepage) bt when i press back button it just refresh and keep showing tabspage only doesn't prompt the option to exit.and no error in the console related to the code